# Minimizer of the Monge problem $\frac{1}{2}\int_A |x-T(x)|^2dx$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations, optimal-transport

I'm studying for an exam and there I'm having trouble to solve this exercise, if you could help me it would be great.

Given $A =\{x\in \mathbb{R}^2:|x|<1\}$ and $B=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^2:1<|x|<\sqrt{2}\}$, consider the measures $\mu=\mathfrak{L}^2|_A$ and $\nu=\mathfrak{L}^2|_B$.

Compute the map $T:\nabla\varphi:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$, with $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ convex, solving Monge's minimum problem
$$ \min\bigg\{\frac{1}{2}\int_A|x-T(x)|^2dx:T\in \mathfrak{T}(\mu,\nu)\bigg\}.$$

Assume radial symmetry and regularity, $\varphi\in C^2(A)$.

In here $\tau\in \mathfrak{T}(\mu,\nu)$  if $\tau:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is Borel and $\tau_\#\mu=\nu$, and
$ \tau_{\#}\mu(B)=\mu(\tau^{-1})B\; $ for $ B\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ Borel.

I know that a solution exists thanks to the Brenier Lemma:

> Let $\mu,\nu$ be two Borel measures in $m\mathbb{R}^n$ with compact support, $\mu(\mathbb{R}^n)=\nu(\mathbb{R}^n)<\infty$ and $\mu<<\mathfrak{L}^n.$
>
> Then there is a convex function $\varphi:\mathbb{
>  R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\tau=\nabla \varphi$ realizes the minimum
> $$ \min \bigg\{
>  \frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|x-\tau(x)|^2d\mu|
>  \tau_\#
>  \mu=\nu 
>  \bigg\}.$$

However I have problems in actually computing the minimizer, the course is about calculus of variations but until now I only solved problems using Euler-Lagrange equations and this doesn't seem the case to do so.

Comment: My intuition tells me that it's easier to look at it in polar coordinates and then interpolate between the radius... so something like $re^{i\varphi} \mapsto (1 + (\sqrt(2) - 1)r)e^{i\varphi}$ seems like an interesting candidate to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solutions to the Monge minimization problem can be constructed explicitely on $\mathbb{R}$, and since you assume radial symmetry, the problem you want to solve is $1$-dimensional.

For instance, how can you send optimally the measure with density $\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]} (x)$ to the measure with density $y \mathbf{1}_{[0,\sqrt{2}]} (y)$? Well, the minimizer $T$ is nondecreasing (from your point of view : it is the gradient of a convex function), and such that $T_* (\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]} (x) \text{d}x) = y \mathbf{1}_{[0,\sqrt{2}]} (y) \text{d}y$. Already, looking at the supports, we get $T(0) = 0$ and $T(1) = \sqrt{2}$. In addition, for all continuous and bounded functions $f$,

$$\int_0^1 f(x) \ \text{d}x =  \int_0^{\sqrt{2}} f(T^{-1} (y)) y \ \text{d}y  = \int_0^1 f(x) T(x) T' (x) \ \text{d}x,$$

the first equality being the constraint $T_* (\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]} (x) \text{d}x) = y \mathbf{1}_{[0,\sqrt{2}]} (y) \text{d}y$ and the second equality a change of variables $y = T(x)$. Since this holds for all $f$, we get, for (almost) all $x \in [0,1]$,

$$T(x) = \frac{1}{T' (x)}.$$

Solving this differential equation yields directly $T(x) = \sqrt{2x}$. Extend as you wish outside of $[0,1]$.

In your case, as I said, you can use the radial symmetry of the solution:

$$\int_A f(\mathbb{r}) \ \text{d}\mathbb{r} = \int_B f(T^{-1} (\mathbb{r}')) \ \text{d}\mathbb{r}' = \int_A f(\mathbb{r}) | \text{det} DT |(\mathbb{r}) \ \text{d}\mathbb{r},$$

whence $| \text{det} DT |(\mathbb{r}) = 1$ for (almost) all $\mathbb{r} \in A$. In addition, $T(\mathbb{0}) = \mathbb{0}$.The radial symmetry lets you compute $T$ from there.

You an also exploit the radial symmetry more directly. Writing $T(\mathbb{r}) = t(\mathbb{r}) \mathbb{u}_{\mathbb{r}}$, and restricting ourselves to radially symmetric functions,

$$\int_0^1 f(x) 2 \pi x \ \text{d}x = \int_A f(\mathbb{r}) \ \text{d}\mathbb{r} = \int_B f(T^{-1} (\mathbb{r}')) \ \text{d}\mathbb{r}' =  \int_1^{\sqrt{2}} f(t^{-1} (y)) 2 \pi y \ \text{d}y = \int_0^1 f(x) 2 \pi t(x) t'(x) \ \text{d}x,$$

and you can extract a differential equation to compute $t$.

Comment: Doesn't this give us a solution that doens't depend on the specific problem?
If I got it right I can obtain a solution starting from |detDT|(r) which doesn't seem to be linked up with my cost function or anything at all but itself

Comment: @Frankie123 : The condition $|Det DT| = 1$ appears because both the source and the target densities are $1$ on their support ; otherwise, you would get something like $\rho_A (r) = \rho_B(T(r)) |det DT| (r)$, where $\rho_A$ is the source density and $\rho_B$ the target density. First point where the specificities of the problem appears.

Comment: In addition : the condition $|Det DT| = 1$ is degenerate (it is not enough to recover $T$ is general). The radial symmetry of the problem is what allows you to finish from there.

Comment: Finally : the bounds of $A$ and $B$ appear as limit conditions for the differential equation $|Det DT| = 1$. Chang anything about $A$ and $B$, and one of theses points break down, and you don't get the same transformation $T$.

Comment: Ok but what about |x-T(x)|^2, how does that factor in?
And I'm still not sure about how that solution is linked to the minimizer

Comment: That does not factor in. The gist of my answer is that the constraints we have on the solution $T$ (sends the uniform measure on $A$ to the uniforme measure on $B$, radially symmetric, monotone/gradient of a convex function) are already enough to determine it.

Comment: Oh, very interesting